# How to implement swift Dictionary on our own logic

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, generic-programming, generic-collections

I'm trying to implement the actual implementation of swift dictionary. I want to know how to ignore the array variable **boxes** in the output code. Also is this exactly what the actual implementation of dictionary is?

```
struct Box<U,V> where U: Hashable {

    var que: U
    var ans:V

    fileprivate var boxes = [Box]()

    init(_ que: U,ans: V) {
        self.que = que
        self.ans = ans
    }

    mutating func addBox(with que: U, ans: V) {
        boxes.append(Box(que, ans: ans))
    }

    mutating func deleteBox(_ que: U) {
        for (index, value) in boxes.enumerated() {
            if value.que == que {
                boxes.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Display {

    func show() {
        var dict = Box(1, ans: "One")
        print(dict)
    }
}

let obj = Display()
obj.show()
```

//Output: Box(que: 1, ans: "One", **boxes: []**)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know how to ignore the array variable boxes in the output code

Conform Box to CustomStringConvertible and provide your own `description` implementation.

> Also is this exactly what the actual implementation of dictionary is?

No.

Answer (score 1):

To properly display your object use the protocol `CustomStringConvertible` as matt said in another post.

For the actual implementation of Dictionary in Swift, you can find it in the open source GitHub repository managed by Apple [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift) (spoiler: it is a little bit more complicated than what you coded).